# Search more strings in a query sql

Tags: sql, string

Can you help me to complete this query ?

```
SELECT id_category FROM wrs_category_lang 
WHERE id_lang = 5 
AND name = keyword1, keyword2 with spaces, keyword3;
```

I wish to get all ids from `id_category` that corresponds to a list of name. The column `name` is of type `varchar(128)`. Thanks !

Comment: the only query that works is this:  SELECT id_category FROM wrs_category_lang WHERE id_lang = 5 AND name LIKE '%prodotti%wrs%'; but in which way can i specify more values ?

Comment: Can you also post your tables if you are using multiple tables to connect with eachother

Comment: query is right, the real problem was spaces before keyword in mysql (bugged module for import product in prestashop)..so EMPTY SET was right..i tried to search "keyword" but in db was " keyword" THANKS TO ALL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you asking for IN statement?:

```
SELECT id_category 
FROM wrs_category_lang 
WHERE id_lang = 5 AND name IN('keyword1','keyword2'...);
```

Comment: yeah ! the query is right, because if i try to search all keywords (about 50 keywords) name IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3' .... it returns only few ids and not all ! but EVERY keyword in field 'name' has its own id !!! very very strange....

Comment: SOLVED: i've spaces in field name, before every keyword...unbelievable..sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT id_category 
FROM wrs_category_lang 
WHERE id_lang = 5 
AND name IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2 with spaces', 'keyword3');
```

Comment: your query show me an epty set..i'm explain better: I want to get all the ids that match the list of words.. and some words have spaces, THANKS!